# Create a mouse selection box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I writing the following code, and I'm trying to create a selection box when user click and drag the mouse

```js
var draggingMouse = false;
var leftMouseDrag, topMouseDrag;
$(document).on("mousedown mouseup", "#cloud_main_page", function(e){ 
 if (e.type == "mousedown") {
  draggingMouse = true;
  var offset = $(this).offset();
  
  leftMouseDrag = e.pageX - offset.left;
  topMouseDrag = e.pageY - offset.top
  
  $("#cloud_main_page .cloud_mouse_selection").css({"top": topMouseDrag, "left" : leftMouseDrag});
   
 } else{
  draggingMouse = false; 
  $("#cloud_main_page .cloud_mouse_selection").removeAttr("style");
 }
  
}).on("mousemove", "#cloud_main_page", function(e){
 if(draggingMouse){
  var offsetDrag = $("#cloud_main_page .cloud_mouse_selection").offset();
   
  var top = e.pageY - offsetDrag.top;
  var left = e.pageX - offsetDrag.left;
      
  var width = Math.abs(left);
  var height = Math.abs(top);
   
  $("#cloud_main_page .cloud_mouse_selection").css({"width": width, "height": height});
 }
});
```

```css
#cloud_main_page{
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
  
  position:relative;
}
#cloud_main_page .cloud_mouse_selection{ 
 position:absolute;
 
 background-color:rgba(6, 217, 160, 0.05);
 border: 1px solid rgba(6, 217, 160, 0.3); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cloud_main_page">
  <div class="cloud_mouse_selection"></div>
</div>
```

It works well since the user drags only from left to right, and from top to bottom... So I would like to improve it, making in a way that no matter which direction the user drags the mouse, the box will follow it, how can I do that?

Comment: Why you delete the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can't have a negative width/height, you need to change the origin of the box.

You can do that by changing the css the same way you are changing the width and height.

For each direction, if the difference is < 0, you want to set the position of the box to the mouse position.
Something like:

```
if(top < 0){
    $("#cloud_main_page .cloud_mouse_selection").css({"top": e.pageY});
}else{
    $("#cloud_main_page .cloud_mouse_selection").css({"top": topMouseDrag});
}
//same for left
```

Now if you only change that you'll run into an issue, because you are using the offset of the box instead of the origin position of the start of the drag. You can resolve this issue by changing

```
var top = e.pageY - offsetDrag.top;
```

to

```
var top = e.pageY - topMouseDrag;
```

this way, the width and height will **always** be calculated from the origin of the drag.

Here is your snippet with the modification:

```js
var draggingMouse = false;
var leftMouseDrag, topMouseDrag;
$(document).on("mousedown mouseup", "#cloud_main_page", function(e){ 
 if (e.type == "mousedown") {
  draggingMouse = true;
  var offset = $(this).offset();
  
  leftMouseDrag = e.pageX - offset.left;
  topMouseDrag = e.pageY - offset.top
  
  $("#cloud_main_page .cloud_mouse_selection").css({"top": topMouseDrag, "left" : leftMouseDrag});
   
 } else{
  draggingMouse = false; 
  $("#cloud_main_page .cloud_mouse_selection").removeAttr("style");
 }
  
}).on("mousemove", "#cloud_main_page", function(e){
 if(draggingMouse){
            var offsetDrag = $("#cloud_main_page .cloud_mouse_selection").offset();
            
            var top = e.pageY - topMouseDrag;
            var left = e.pageX - leftMouseDrag;

            var width = Math.abs(left);
            var height = Math.abs(top);

            if(top < 0){
               $("#cloud_main_page .cloud_mouse_selection").css({"top": e.pageY });
            }else{
                $("#cloud_main_page .cloud_mouse_selection").css({"top": topMouseDrag});
            }

            if(left < 0){
                $("#cloud_main_page .cloud_mouse_selection").css({"left": e.pageX});
            }else{
                $("#cloud_main_page .cloud_mouse_selection").css({"left": leftMouseDrag});
            }


        $("#cloud_main_page .cloud_mouse_selection").css({"width": width, "height": height});
 }
});
```

```css
#cloud_main_page{
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
  
  position:relative;
}
#cloud_main_page .cloud_mouse_selection{ 
 position:absolute;
 
 background-color:rgba(6, 217, 160, 0.05);
 border: 1px solid rgba(6, 217, 160, 0.3); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cloud_main_page">
  <div class="cloud_mouse_selection"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you show your answer using JS?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Vanilla javascript version of the Excellent Answer posted by Liora. Make sure the `mouse_selection_box` div's css `position` value is set to `fixed`.

```
      const mouseSelectDom = document.querySelector('.mouse_selection_box');
      let draggingMouse = false;
      let leftMouseDrag, topMouseDrag;
      const startDrag = (e) => {
         if (e.type === 'mousedown') {
            draggingMouse = true;
            const offset = mouseSelectDom.getBoundingClientRect();

            leftMouseDrag = e.pageX - offset.left;
            topMouseDrag = e.pageY - offset.top;

            console.log(e.pageX, offset.left, leftMouseDrag);
            console.log(e.pageY, offset.top, topMouseDrag);

            mouseSelectDom.style.top = topMouseDrag + 'px';
            mouseSelectDom.style.left = leftMouseDrag + 'px';
         }
      };
      const stopDrag = () => {
         draggingMouse = false;
         leftMouseDrag = 0;
         topMouseDrag = 0;
         document.querySelector('.mouse_selection_box').removeAttribute('style');
      };
      const getDragSize = (e) => {
         if (draggingMouse) {
            // const offsetDrag = mouseSelectDom.getBoundingClientRect();
            const top = e.pageY - topMouseDrag;
            const left = e.pageX - leftMouseDrag;

            const width = Math.abs(left);
            const height = Math.abs(top);

            if (top < 0) {
               mouseSelectDom.style.top = e.pageY + 'px';
            } else {
               mouseSelectDom.style.top = topMouseDrag + 'px';
            }

            if (left < 0) {
               mouseSelectDom.style.left = e.pageX + 'px';
            } else {
               mouseSelectDom.style.left = leftMouseDrag + 'px';
            }
            mouseSelectDom.style.width = width + 'px';
            mouseSelectDom.style.height = height + 'px';
         }
      };
      window.addEventListener('mousedown', startDrag);
      window.addEventListener('mouseup', stopDrag);
      window.addEventListener('mousemove', getDragSize);
```